# SVN working with 2 remote branches

Tags: svn, branch

I have two remote branches. My_branch and Production.
I created a folder called Project and checked out the My_branch into it so I have a working copy on my filesystem in Project/My_branch. I will want to make some changes on this branch and after commiting everything merge them to second branch Production so the will appera there. I as understood after a research, I need a working copy of Production branch also, so I need to to another checkout on that folder Project from Production branch, so I will have Project/My_branch and Project/Production. Than I need to do all needed changes on My_branch, commit them and than go to Production directory

```
svn merge https://my/repo/address/branches/Production https://my/repo/address/branches/My_branch
```

and that's it?

Comment: You do not merge directly into another branch, you have to merge to your local checkout of the target branch. Then you also need to specify a range of revisions to merge. And in case of any conflicts you have to resolve those prior to committing to the production branch. Apart from that: yes, that's all. Easy.

Comment: so how should the exact command look like? including revisions list? can I write something like from revision 123 to head? or i need to specify declared scope like from 123 to 125

Comment: I would _always_ prefer to specify some specific version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read SVN Book about merging, or, at least, `svn help merge`: your merge is totally wrong
2. In order to merge `SOMETHING` into `ANOTHER` you have to

   - Have Working Copy of ANOTHER (clean WC, updatedand without local modifications) - you done it
   - cd to the root of this WC - you done it
   - Merge SOMETHING to WC - `svn merge SOMETHING`, resolve (possible) conflicts, commit mergeset

Comment: I have 2 Working copies of 2 branches (on my filesystem). They were exactly the same on the beginning, both up to date and clean.. I made some changes on one of them, added changes, commited them. Now to have those changes also on second branch I need to merge them. Initial revision was 1000 now i have 1003 on modified one and still 1000 on the second branch. I want ot have 1003 on both of them. Nothing changed on the second branch so there won't be any conflicts. How I specify branches name in the svn merge cmd-just give their names? and how to specify what revision I want to merge.

Comment: @olechafm - branch name specified by **full URL** of branch (or with shorthand ^), defining range **is not needed** and bad practice - SVN *in most casual cases* is smart enough to detect merge-range by himself

Comment: but i'm still not sure have I prepared it like I should... I've checkedout both branches so I have two folders now named after those branches in a directory... I edited one of them commited and they are both clean now. I'm trying to do diff on them by svn diff C:dir\to\branch1name C:dir\to\branch2name and it doesnt show anything

Comment: @olechafm - for diff|merge you must use **URL of remote** resource (URL for *repository*), not local path